# Stop a gulp watch task?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I stop a running gulp watch task without having to completely exit the program?

I can see the task running on the task bar bottom left with a spinning "slashes" character.

There appears to be a command "Terminate running task" (that can optionally be bound to a keyboard short-cut) - but executing this command doesn't seem to do anything and the task continues to run.  Is this feature not implemented yet in the current preview version (0.1.0)?

Comment: strange, Terminate Running Task terminates the running Gulp watch task for me running on Windows 8

Comment: Terminating works for me as well. On which OS are you?

Comment: I'm on Windows 8.1.  Hmm .. strange.... maybe it has something to do with my gulp task?  The project is a NodeJS app.  The task starts up nodemon & BrowserSync before doing the watch.

Comment: Do you get any feedback in the `Output for 'tasks'` pane when selecting "Terminate Running Task" from the command palette? Can you simplify your gulp task to the bare essentials to rule out something caused by a forked process (?) or something else weird that VSC wouldn't be able to track/kill?

Comment: If you are using PC, try the "pause/brake" key

Answer (score 18):

In case others run across this question, open the Command Palette (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> on Windows, <kbd>Command+Shift+P</kbd> on OSX, and search for "Terminate Running Task."

Comment: Ehm, the op specifically mentioned that the `Terminate Tunning Task` option doesn't work for him! Or was that a later edit? Anyway I have the same issue: the `Terminate Running Task` doesn't stop a running Gulp (watch) task.

Comment: "Terminate Running Task" works for me, it stopped watch gulp task. VSC v0.10.6 on Win7Pro

Answer (score 7):

If you ever wonder what

> search for "Terminate Running Task."

does behind the scenes: "workbench.action.tasks.terminate".

so you can just bind it, like this:

```
{ "key": "ctrl+shift+t", "command": "workbench.action.tasks.terminate" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue from 2-3 months. Today I just opened tasks.json and saw hint that isWatching is deprecated instead use isBackground. I changed it and ran the task and terminated ,Voila it's working.

In short- Open tasks.json. If you see isWatching property on task change it to isBackground.